Strong LLN for holding times of CTMC
Let $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a CTMC with finite state space $S$ and irreducible transition matrix. In addition, let $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be the jump chain and $T_n$ the time of the n-th transition. Recall that
$$t(x):= \mathbb E[T_{i+1}-T_i\mid Y_i=x]=\mathbb E_x[\tau_{S\setminus \{x\}}]=\frac{1}{-q(x,x)}$$
is the expected value of the holding time of $x$ and
$$t_n(x):=\frac{\int_0^{T_n}1_{\{x\}}(X_t)|dt|}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1_{\{x\}}(Y_i)}$$
is the sample mean, i.e. the total time the system spent in $x$ divided by the number of times the system visited $x$ (if we measure up to time $T_n$). Is it true that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n(x)=t(x)?$$
Note that if we define $e_n=c(X_n)(T_{n+1}-T_n)$, then $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is a sequence of iid mean one exponential RVs and we are actually trying to show the following variation of the LLN:
$$\forall x\in S:1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1_{\{x\}}(Y_i)}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1_{\{x\}}(Y_i)e_i$$
